# Worklight 6.2 Native iOS auto provisioning handle challenge

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

I am trying to implement auto provisioning for native iOS app with Worklight 6.2 and I am stuck on point, that my app is not able to react on auto provisioning challenge from the server. From the documentation, app should trigger provisioning (create certificate signing request), but the app is not doing it. All I get from server is this:

```
/*-secure-
{
    "challenges": 
    {
        "wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm": 
        {
            "ID": 
            {
                "allowed":true, "token":"m4c5j0gqmv7kuf52idh6fh4jjl", "entity":"application"
            }
        }
    }
}
*/
```

Also, I didn't found any options how to create custom provisioning for native iOS app, but I would be ok with default auto provisioning.

My authenticationConfig.xml looks like this:

```
<customSecurityTest name="customTests">
        <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="1"/>
        <test realm="wl_deviceAutoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

Head of my applicationDescriptor.xml looks like this:

```
<nativeIOSApp xmlns="http://www.worklight.com/native-ios-descriptor"
  bundleId="com.iOSNativeAdapterBasedAuth" id="iOSNativeAdapterBasedAuth"
  platformVersion="6.2.0.00.20140613-0730" version="1.0" securityTest="customTests">
```

So, my question is, is there any way or some example how to do this or should it work automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight v5.x - v6.2 does not provide `auto-provisioning` challenge handlers for the supported native environments (iOS, Android, WP8).

Only `no-provisioning` is supported at this time.